# Access collection from within partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I render a collection using a partial, I would like to have access to the collection itself from within the partial (I already know how to access the current member).

1. How do I access the whole collection from within the partial (best without passing the collection as a parameter)?
2. I would specifically like to check if the current member being rendered is the last in the collection. How do I do that? (Elegantly, I mean).

PS. I don't have the collection as an instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to reference the original collection from inside the action, nor to check if it's the latest.

From inside the collection you have access to the `<partial>_counter` variable (in case the partial is called `_post`, the name of the variable is `post_counter`) that indicates the number of the item you are rendering in the collection (from 0 to collection.size-1).

But apart from this, no reference to the whole collection.

The only solution, so far, is probably to pass it as locals.